# Conditional to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame and y have 2 columns, A and B. Column A has some null values so I want to create a column C like this, if A have a null value then take the value of B, else take the value of A. I am using this code but it´s not working:

```
if data['A'] is None:
    data['C'] = data['B']
else:
    data['C'] = data['A']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) -

```
data['C'] = data['A'].fillna(data['B'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the exact sample code, **you are missing a Semi-quotation mark on line 2 after C**, otherwise you can do this:

Use **isnull** instead of *is None*

```
import pandas as pd

data =  pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,None], 'B': [3, 4]})

if data['A'].isnull:
    data['C'] = data['B']
else:
    data['C'] = data['A']

print (data['C'].values)
```

Output [3 4]

Here is a link to pandas official doc, [DataFrame.isnull](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html)